# How to sort the array of objects based on a parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object in response as a json like:

```
const arr = [{
    Mandatory: false,
    Question: 65,
    QuestionType: "E",
    YesNo: "n",
    type: "QuestionOutput"
  },
  {
    Mandatory: false,
    Question: 64,
    QuestionType: "H",
    YesNo: "n",
    type: "QuestionOutput"
  },
  {
    Mandatory: false,
    Question: 85,
    QuestionType: "S",
    YesNo: "n",
    type: "QuestionOutput"
  },
  {
    Mandatory: false,
    Question: 61,
    QuestionType: "F",
    YesNo: "",
    type: "QuestionOutput"
  },
  {
    Mandatory: true,
    Question: 60,
    QuestionType: "F",
    YesNo: "",
    type: "QuestionOutput"
  }
];
```

I want to sort this array in ascending order based on the property Question and put the sorted object array into another object array.

Comment: Do you mean sort alphabetically? What is the logic you wish to sort by?

Comment: format that thing please

Comment: I don't think is duplicate because here the object property value is an `integer`

Comment: @YosvelQuintero: there are plenty of other duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with the syntax `arr.sort(compareFunction)`, and notice that as the property value in your object is an `integer` you can sort:

- **ASC**: `arr.sort((a, b) => a.Question - b.Question)`
- **DESC**: `arr.sort((a, b) => b.Question - a.Question)`

Code:

```js
const arr = [{Mandatory: false,Question: 65,QuestionType: "E",YesNo: "n",type: "QuestionOutput"},{Mandatory: false,Question: 64,QuestionType: "H",YesNo: "n",type: "QuestionOutput"},{Mandatory: false,Question: 85,QuestionType: "S",YesNo: "n",type: "QuestionOutput"},{Mandatory: false,Question: 61,QuestionType: "F",YesNo: "",type: "QuestionOutput"},{Mandatory: true,Question: 60,QuestionType: "F",YesNo: "",type: "QuestionOutput"}];

arr.sort((a, b) => a.Question - b.Question);
console.log('arr:', arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```